# Responding very slow while loading icons

Tags: xubuntu, performance

I have just installed Xubuntu 12.04 x32 from a USB on to my hard drive. It installed fine, however now when I boot up and log in to my user, it seems to be rather slow -- notifications at the top right have sort of a gray shadow background, probably a transparacy bug (however this fixes itself after a while). It takes about a  minute for the Xfce panel to load completely as well ask the desktop.

When I click the menu icon, it freezes for about half a minute. When I hovered over a section, for example Settings, the options showed however the icons were still loading, and my computer froze for about two minutes, when the icons then appeared.

I am not completely sure what the cause is, but after about five minutes after everything settles fine. It's quite annoying to have to wait ~10 minutes for Xubuntu to start up, so does anyone know what the issue could possibly be, and how I could fix it?

Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More information will help, run these from a terminal and give us that

```
lspci
```

Try turning off compositing - go to system settings then window manager tweaks

[image]

[image]

See if that helps.

You can also start start `top` from a terminal and monitor processes - those at top will be taking most cpu

[image]